# VGA and HDMI, can i connect both?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a laptop (Asus 73G) that has both outputs, HDMI and VGA.  Can I connect both to two different monitors?

I can't try it since I don't have a HDMI cable so i'm asking if anyone knows if that is possible.

Gut feeling tells me that it will probably not work..

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.  The more resolution the mobile graphics card has to push, the less stable it will be. Dual external displays driven by the mobile graphics card would be very iffy for gaming, but likely ok (based on the following external forum post) if you just need more general desktop usage real estate:

[GeForce GTX 460M Dual Display resolutions](http://www.kobaltcomputers.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?0&p=27357)